# Way to see the date roles were assigned?

Tags: ubercart, users

Is there a way to setup a view in drupal 6 that shows me users assigned new roles in the last month and who assigned the role?

I have video products that sell both through the online store and at the front desk of various martial arts schools. Currently the online portion is handled with ubercart granting access to appropriate roles. However tracking the sales from the front desk is messy, using the role watchdog module and filtering the email notifications.

Being able to see all role modifications in the last month would simplify tracking of sales to each school greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For D6, check out the [User Role History](http://drupal.org/project/user_role_history) module

Answer (score 1):

You could create a content type User Role, then with Rules module register when a role it's assigned.

Comment: An advanced way instead of using Rules, will be create your own module and using hook hook_user_role_update, then programatically create content User Role.

Answer (score 0):

Not currently possible; see http://drupal.org/node/1263032

Comment: Well that is role watchdog itself needing a patch to enable it in views (which would be nice). Outside of role watchdog  do role assignments not get timestamped in some way? Seems like it should be logged someplace but I can't find it.

Comment: No, role assignments are not timestamped unless you add code (role_watchdog, or see other answers) to do so. If you want to use role_watchdog, see also http://drupal.org/node/1408090. Building your own role_watchdog with Rules, as suggested by @ropic, is another fine option.

Comment: Sweet lots of options then. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I posted my latest improvements to role_watchdog to http://drupal.org/node/1516742. The latest patch implements 1408090, but with pagers.  Only the d6 version is available at the moment, but I'll do a d7 version eventually.  Don't know if the maintainer is or is not going to be interested in og support, though, which is my primary need.

Comment: Added your improvements patch and they work fantastic!